# Rally Lookback API filter on a custom field not working as expected

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I have User Stories , and want to track the changes in a custom field C_L3KanbanStage, for my stories in between a date.

Is this possible. The problem I am facing, is that, I am not getting expected output.

As per my understanding, this field C_L3KanbanStage, being a drop down field, I should be able to use the comparison operators, but somehow it is not working

```
{
  "_ProjectHierarchy": XXXXX,
  "ObjectID": XXXX,
  "c_L3KanbanStage": {
    "$lt": "Closed"
  },
  "_ValidFrom": {
    "$gte": "2014-03-03",
    "$lt": "2014-04-15"
  }
}
```

It should give me all lesser values then "Closed", but it gives me only one value.

However, if I try:

```
{
  "_ProjectHierarchy": XXXX,
  "ObjectID": XXXX,
  "c_L3KanbanStage": "In Progress",
  "_ValidFrom": {
    "$gte": "2014-03-03",
    "$lt": "2014-04-15"
  }
}
```

Then it gives me two snapshots. I am not sure, if I am trying something wrong or missing something. Can somebody please help me on this.

Basically I want to achieve something like, within two dates
I want to get each transition in the value for c_L3KanbanStage

```
{
  "_ProjectHierarchy": XXXXX,
  "ObjectID": XXXXX,
  "_PreviousValues.c_L3KanbanStage": {"$in": ["Advance Investigation"]},
  "c_L3KanbanStage": {"$in": ["Closed","Verified"]}
}
```

Can any one please help me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should work, but here are some reasons you might not get the expected query results.

If you query by ObjectID, you should only need to specify _ProjectHierarchy if the artifact moved from one project to another at some point.  Try removing that.

```
{
  "ObjectID": XXXXX,
  "_PreviousValues.c_L3KanbanStage": { "$in": ["Advance Investigation"] },
  "c_L3KanbanStage": { "$in": ["Closed","Verified"] }
}
```

You can also use $gt and $lt for state fields.  For example,

```
{
  "ObjectID": XXXXX,
  "c_L3KanbanStage": { "$gte": "Closed" },
  "_PreviousValues.c_L3KanbanStage": { "$lt": "Closed" }    
}
```

Once you see the expected snapshots without specifying a date range, try adding that part to the query.

```
{
   "ObjectID": XXXXX,
   "c_L3KanbanStage": { "$gte": "Closed" },
   "_PreviousValues.c_L3KanbanStage": { "$lt": "Closed" } 
   "_ValidFrom": {
     "$gte": "2014-03-03",
     "$lt": "2014-04-15"
   } 
}
```

In case it helps, the Lookback API documentation has [examples of state transition queries](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/tryitnow/scenario5).

Comment: Thanks john. However as I had mentioned, when I am using the project hierarchy, then also the  "c_L3KanbanStage": "In Progress",, gives results but  "c_L3KanbanStage": {
    "$lt": "Closed"
  } does not gives them. This is what is confusing me more

Comment: I tried that as well, sir. But does not help. I tried {
    "ObjectID": XXXX,
    "c_L3KanbanStage": {
        "$gte": "Closed"
    },
    "_PreviousValues.c_L3KanbanStage": {
        "$lt": "Closed"
    }
}

Comment: If you remove the date boundaries, do the snapshots show expected progression?  Try sort: { _SnapshotNumber: 1 } and fields: true  to improve readability.  Could there be something odd in the life of this artifact that's producing odd results?  Also, does c_L3KanbanStage show strings or OIDs.  My suggestions assume strings.

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply on this. The expected snapshots are only seen if I use equal operator, as soon as I try to use comparison operators, it stops working. Also c_L3KanbanStage, shows string itself, hence I dont think this has to do with OID's. I believe, that somehow, Rally is not understanding the hierarchy for the drop down field.

Comment: Hello John, Is there a way I can confirm that Rally understands the hierarchy for my field?

Comment: I think it's more an order than a hierarchy.  The ordering is determined by the list of values when you edit a multivalue custom field.  You can verify this in the field editing screen.